# PUSH-000183: handler left no space in buffer

Tags: push-diffusion

I keep seeing the following warning and stack trace in the server log and would like to know what is going wrong and how to fix it. I checked [the designation PUSH-000183](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.6.6/manual/html/administratorguide/diagnostics/logs/PUSH-000183.html), but it only says "A communication error has occurred on a message channel."

```
2016-04-20 13:37:42.452|WARN|Diffusion: InboundThreadPool Thread_1|PUSH-000183|Message channel error: 'NIOBufferedChannel@571714020[connected local=/10.96.130.21:8070 remote=/10.96.1.36:24832] : Closed(UNEXPECTED_ERROR) ServerInboundTask@542477fd HTTPConnectionHandler@2641ae33[partial request - more expected]: handler left no space in buffer ' caused by 'ServerInboundTask@542477fd HTTPConnectionHandler@2641ae33[partial request - more expected]: handler left no space in buffer'.|com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.message.MessageChannelException
com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.message.MessageChannelException: ServerInboundTask@542477fd HTTPConnectionHandler@2641ae33[partial request - more expected]: handler left no space in buffer
at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.nio.NIOBufferedChannel.logClosingException(NIOBufferedChannel.java:647)
at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.nio.NIOBufferedChannel.logAndClose(NIOBufferedChannel.java:613)
at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.nio.AbstractReadSelector$InboundTask.close(AbstractReadSelector.java:410)
at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.nio.AbstractReadSelector$InboundTask.run(AbstractReadSelector.java:351)
at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.threads.FastThreadPool$PoolWorker.run(FastThreadPool.java:783)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServerInboundTask@542477fd HTTPConnectionHandler@2641ae33[partial request - more expected]: handler left no space in buffer
at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.io.nio.AbstractReadSelector$InboundTask.run(AbstractReadSelector.java:324)
```

Is this only limited to clients connecting using XHR or would websockets also be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when a client sends a message to the server that is bigger 
than the configured input-buffer-size in [Connectors.xml](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.1/manual/html/administratorguide/configuration/Connectors.html).

It will disconnect the client which may then reconnect if it has been [configured 
to do so](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.1.18/manual/html/tuning/clientreconnect/c_clientreconnection.html). This can happen to any client regardless of the transport 
(XHR, Websockets, etc).

You will need to increase the input-buffer-size in [Connectors.xml](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.1/manual/html/administratorguide/configuration/Connectors.html) to 
match the biggest message that you expect. For example if you are 
sending messages up to 256K in size you could use the following 
configuration:

```
<socket-conditioning>
     <!-- If this value is less than max-message-size defined in 
          Server.xml, it will be
          overwritten by the latter. -->
     <input-buffer-size>256k</input-buffer-size>
     <!-- Other config... -->
</socket-conditioning>
```